# Read appsettings.{env}.json objects in .NET 6 API - Values coming as NULL

Tags: c#, json, api, .net-6.0

I am using `.NET 6` to create APIs.
I have environment-based `appsettings.json` files.

I have created apt profiles in `launchSettings.json` as well.

I am trying to use `Options` pattern to read the key/values inside one of the controllers.

I get the values as `NULL` every single time.

When I debug the Program.cs file, I am able to see the proper values via the below line of code.

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection(key: "Config").Get<Config>();
```

Please help. Code used is as below:

**Program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true);

builder.Configuration.GetSection(key: "Config").Get<Config>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Config>();
```

**Config.cs:**

```
public class Config
    {
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

**ProductsController.cs**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository _repository;
        private readonly Config _config;

        public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository,
            IOptions<Config> config)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _config = config.Value;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/configs")]
        public IActionResult GetConfigs()
        {
            var model = new { type = _config.Type, env = _config.Environment };
            return Ok(model);
        }
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Config": {
    "Environment": "local",
    "Type": "local Server"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Config": {
    "Environment": "Development",
    "Type": "Development Server"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Staging.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Config": {
    "Environment": "Staging",
    "Type": "Staging Server"
  }
}
```

**launchSettings.json:**

```
 "profiles": {
    "API - Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7082;http://localhost:5082",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "API - Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might need to use `configuration.GetSection` in [`Services.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces) which means registering `Config` object from `Config` section of *appsettings.json*.

```
builder.Services.Configure<Config>(configuration.GetSection("Config"));
```

Comment: Let me try, thank you for answerng.

Comment: This works, thank you. I now understand the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is within:

```
configuration
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true);

builder.Configuration.GetSection(key: "Config").Get<Config>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Config>();
```

You're currently getting a section `Config` and then calling `Get<>` on it but never applying that to anything (injecting).  It would seem like the final line would do that, but there is no parameter to this function to provide something to inject.

You could:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Config>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Config"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it. It works. But @D-Shih answered it before you, hence I had to accept his answer. But I very much love your explanation and understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddOptions<Config>()
    .Bind(configuration.GetSection("Config"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations(); // optionally validate annotations
```

Try using AddOptions, this should then bind.